# SQL server returns result immediately

Tags: sql-server

Yesterday I had this strange (never seen before) situation when applying a patch to several databases from with SQL server management studio. I needed to update a large table (5 Million records+) over several databases. The statement I issued per database was something like:

```
set rowcount 100000
select 1
while @@rowcount > 1
  update table
  set column = newval
  where column is null
```

Those statements ran for several seconds (anywhere between 2 and 30 seconds). On a second tab I ran this query:

```
  select count(*) 
  from table 
  where column is null
```

Just to check how many rows where already processed. Impatient as I am, I pressed F5 for the count(*) statements every 20 seconds or so. And the - expected behavior - was that I had to wait for anything in the range from 0 to 30 seconds before the count(*) was calculated. I expected this behavior, since the update statement was running so the count(*) was next in line.

But then after a database or 10 this strange thing happened. I opened the next database (altered the database via USE) and after pressing F5 the count(*) responded immediately. And after pressing F5 again, direct result but without any progress, and again and again, the count(*) did not change. However the update was running.

And then after then n-th press, the count(*) dropped with exactly 100K records. I pressed F5 again, immediate result.. and so on and so on... WHY? wasn't the count(*) waiting... I did not allowed to read dirty or....

Only this database gave me this behavior. And I have really no clue what is causing this.

Between switching database I did not close or open any other tab, so the only thing I can imagine is that the connection parameters for that one database are different. However I'm overlooking those... but I can't find a difference.

Comment: Maybe that database has a different isolation level?

Comment: Check the database settings. Maybe read committed snapshot or/and snapshot isolation level is enabled??

Comment: To be honest: What you are doing is just something one should not do, impatient or not... First of all: loops are *nasty, slow and evil* and I doubt you reall need it (might show your actual statement). Secondly checking the progress with a second connection is like - uhm - pulling grass to let it grow faster :-) Your calls are nothing else then disturbing and making things slower. Better go for a coffee :-)

Comment: @Shnugo It's a database in use with many users reading and writing that table, so I needed a way to throttle the locking of the table... To be fair it's the only way I'm aware off ;-) pulling the grass.... lol

Comment: @Paul hey, I like straight answers :-) So stick to your loop and go for a coffee :-) Btw: From your tiny snippet I take, that you have to set some value to all rows where a specific column is null. This could be done with a `DEFAULT constraint` if the value is fix or with a `TRIGGER`. But I do not know what you are doing there actually...

Comment: @Shnugo that value is now set directly in the procedure responsible for inserting the record in the first place. So in the future that value should never be null again. The update statement was to "fix" old records.

Comment: @Jeffrey both snapshot_isolation_state and read_commited_snapshot  are set to 0 for all databases

Comment: I just created a test database and the only way I can reproduce this behavior is with Snapshot isolation level.... I have no clue about it at this moment.

Comment: Is this done within a Stored Procedure? Might be, that you set the isolation level on transaction level. Thus the general settings would not change...

Comment: @Jeffrey would it be possible to change the isolation level with a shortcut from within the management studio? I ran the exact statement for each database and in between I just changed the current database via the USE statement... furthermore I've checked the snapshot_isolation_state and read_commited_snapshot via sys.databases

Comment: @Shnugo nope not from within a stored procedure straight SQL from within the man. studio

Comment: @Paul, no, I don't think there's a shortcut. This would be rather dangerous actually... if you come back to your database (changing the `USE`) is this behavior back? If there's heavy work all against the same table, might be that you just get some wait cycles...

Comment: @Paul Yes you can change isolation level with SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL [ISOLATION_LEVEL];

Comment: @Jeffrey thanx, I'm aware of that statement, I've checked all settings between the databases (sys.databases) and found no differences. If tried to reproduce this behavior, but it didn't occur anymore... I'm at a dead end...

Comment: This is an old question, but was wondering if you have an index on "column"

Answer (score 0):

as per what I understood from your description above is that you were not getting the result of count(*) correctly on some specific database. If that is the case then, Please use the below script Instead of your count(*)

```
SELECT
COUNT(1)
FROM Table WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE Column IS NULL
```

Because count(*) takes more time to execute. and as your requirement is to just know the count Use Count(1) instead

Also there is a possibility of lock in the database if you are using transactions. So Use the WITH(NOLOCK) to avoid such blocking and get the result more faster.